# pyparsing and line breaks

Tags: python, newline, pyparsing

I just started with `pyparsing` and I have problems with line breaks.

My grammar is:

```
from pyparsing import *

newline = LineEnd () #Literal ('\n').leaveWhitespace ()
minus = Literal ('-')
plus = Literal ('+')
lparen = Literal ('(')
rparen = Literal (')')
ident = Word (alphas)
integer = Word (nums)

arith = Forward ()
parenthized = Group (lparen + arith + rparen)
atom = ident | integer | parenthized

factor = ZeroOrMore (minus | plus) + atom
arith << (ZeroOrMore (factor + (minus | plus) ) + factor)

statement = arith + newline
program = OneOrMore (statement)
```

Now when I parse the following:

```
print (program.parseString ('--1-(-a-3+n)\nx\n') )
```

The result is as expected:

```
['-', '-', '1', '-', ['(', '-', 'a', '-', '3', '+', 'n', ')'], '\n', 'x', '\n']
```

But when the second line can be parsed as tail of the first line, the first `\n` is magicked away?

Code:

```
print (program.parseString ('--1-(-a-3+n)\n-x\n') )
```

Actual result:

```
['-', '-', '1', '-', ['(', '-', 'a', '-', '3', '+', 'n', ')'], '-', 'x', '\n']
```

Expected result:

```
['-', '-', '1', '-', ['(', '-', 'a', '-', '3', '+', 'n', ')'], '\n', '-', 'x', '\n']
```

Actually I don't want the parser to automatically join statements.

**1. What am I doing wrong?**

**2. How can I fix this?**

**3. What is happening under the hood causing this behavious (which surely is sensible, but I just fail to see the point)?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

'\n' is normally skipped over as a whitespace character. If you want '\n' to be significant, then you have to call `setDefaultWhitespaceChars` to remove '\n' as skippable whitespace (you have to do this before defining any of your pyparsing expressions):

```
from pyparsing import *
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' \t')
```

Comment: Is there a non-global way to do this?

Comment: `MY_RULE.setWhitespaceChars("")`

Answer (score 5):

What is happening here is that the parser by default ignores any whitespace.  You need to add the following line of code before you define any elements:

```
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" \t")
```

The normal default whitespace characters are " \t\r\n", I believe.

Edit:  Paul beat me to it.  I should have refreshed after getting dinner together.  :)